# Customizing liferay Calendar portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I'm trying to customize Calendar portlet using this below instructions.
https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en

Its basically **creating Plugins to extend plugins**.
In order to achieve above, I need **"Calendar-portlet.war"** . I don't find any war file for calendar portlet for my version. So i decided to build myself. Then i downloaded Portal plugins source code from here.
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x

Everything's fine but there are some errors exist in JSP pages.

```
initi.jsp ---> The import com.liferay.compat.portal cannot be resolved.
view_calender.jsp--> Duplicate local variable editCalendarURL, Syntax error on token "if", delete this token, ...
```

So, i can't compile n deploy. i'm not sure weather there is a problem with build paths. i followed this too
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47489449

Please help me with any one of these.

1) solving the error issue to successfully build calendar-portlet and create a war file.

2) Just help me finding calendar-portlet.war file.

3) !?Can i create war file from the existing calendar-portlet which is located under \liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps

Version: liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3

Thanks in Advance.

Link for same question in Liferay Forums.
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/54348563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
I got the Correct version of Calendar-portlet from marketplace.

Went to liferay marketplace-->purchased apps-->click on calendar app and Download.

I got **"Calendar-CE.lpkg"** file and found .war file inside it.

Imported as Liferay Binary Plugin in eclipse.

build and deployed. working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> Then i downloaded Portal plugins source code from here. https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x

Don't download from the trunk. Get from a specific tag.

The way we did to customize the calendar portlet, is to download source-code for specific version of calendar porlet and fix-n-build from it.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/calendar-portlet

You can download calendar plugin source code from here.

Comment: I can't find "6.2.0-ga3" version in tags. I'm not familiar with Git. may be missing something silly.

Comment: probably you can go for https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.0-ga1/portlets/calendar-portlet

Comment: Yes,thanks, its working but with little changes.
-->changed build.number=2 (higher than old one). at service.properties.
-->removed JSP Syntax Validator as suggested by liferay.
-->went to Buildpath and removed all errors* (removed missing libraries).

Comment: Hi aston, That version got many bugs. is there anyway that i can get 6.2.0-ga3 version of calender-portlet?

Comment: I'm afraid, can't help you with the bugs part. We also face the same scenario.

Comment: aha, I found a simple way. will post as answer.

Comment: Thank you aston for your support.